# "in" clause, best (fastest) target type for checking

Tags: python

I was doing a project that is doing some stuff, and wanted to print "summary" of the warnings that occurred during processing at the end.

What I did was to store Enums in a list, than for each list member, there is `if` in the last `print_warnings()` method. Something like this:

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.warnings = []

    def foo(self):
        do_something()
        if it_failed:
            self.warnings.append(WarningEnum.foo_failed)


    def print_warnings():
        if WarningEnum.foo_failed in self.warnings:
            print('Very long')
            print('Error message')
            print('With explanaiton')
```

I would really care if `self.warnings` is `tuple` or `list`, or whatever else.
Is there any difference when using `in` clause with different types, like `tuple` or `list` or whatever? Maybe `tuple` is faster than `list`, or `list` is for some reason better than `tuple`. Maybe something completely different is more efficient (like making it `string` and use `unicode` chars instead of `Enum`).

---

Edit: Yes, I know `warnings` shouldn't be initialized this way. I just wanted to save few lines of code in example :)

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity - `x in t` and `x in l` are both O(n). Maybe you could use a set?

Comment: Never initialize a list (or any object) outside the __init__, it will be shared among all the instances.

Answer (score 1):

Since Enum members are hashable, you can use them in a set.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.warnings = set()

    def foo(self):
        do_something()
        if it_failed:
            self.warnings.add(WarningEnum.foo_failed)

    def print_warnings():
        if WarningEnum.foo_failed in self.warnings:
            print('Very long')
            print('Error message')
            print('With explanation')
```

Sets are made for membership tests. No matter how many items they contain, using `in` on them is always quick. Their downside is that they need their items to be hashable, which is the same requirement as dictionary keys have. But Enum members are hashable, so you can use them as set members or dictionary keys.

---

A minor detail, but you had `warnings` as a class variable of `MyClass`, which is probably not what you want, because then all instances of `MyClass` share the same `warnings`.

Comment: FWIW sets are O(1) but with a pretty large constant (hashing), even more so if the set has to be created in place (though that's not the case here). For small number of simple items a tuple or list can be faster despite being O(n), because n is small & k is non-existant.